# How do I create a list in cells choosing from a combobox and selecting a button using VBA?

Tags: list, vba, excel, combobox

I have a combobox filled with values. I want to select a value in the combo box and click the "Add" button to place this value into the some cells below. I can add one item to my list using the following code, but I want to be able to add multiple items. I feel that I am very close, I just need a few tweaks!

```
Private Sub CommandButtonAddItem_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim box As ComboBox
Dim food As String
Dim num As Integer
num = 19


Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set box = ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object

food = box.Value
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(num, 1) = food

If Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(num, 1) = " " Then
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(num, 1) = food

num = num + 1
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **THIS!**

If the "default" cell is already occupied, it'll keep going down untill it finds one that's not empty, to then put the value in that cell.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonAddItem_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim box As ComboBox
Dim food As String
Dim num As Integer
num = 19


Set ws = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set box = ws.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object

food = box.Value

While Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(num, 1) <> ""

    num = num + 1

Wend

Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(num, 1) = food

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems much closer! I thought a while statement would be more appropriate, but I couldn't find a way to get it to work. Help me out a little more please! The compiler gets an "Overflow" error at the "num = num + 1" line. I've never seen this error before, can it be fixed, or is there more to this debugging?

Comment: This means that `num` overflows the max value of the `int`.

Comment: Try to change `num` from an `Integer` to a `Long` or `Variant`

Comment: Thanks! There are still a few errors though. What is the significance of the " <> " When I put them in I get an error as the compiler is looking for an expression between the characters. Without them I get a runtime error saying that an object-defined error.

Comment: Figured it out yet or need me to look into it some more?